# Linear layout overlay with background image

Tags: android, android-drawable

I am trying to **overlay** linear layout on top of background image with  (blending mode like Photoshop).

I can't resolve it.

This is gradient image supposed to be used as app background:

[image]

That's how I want to **overlay** the background image:

[image]

Please help me with sample code or links to the good tutorial.

Comment: Have you tried applying it as a [`android:foreground`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:foreground) attribute in your parent layout?

Comment: Yes, i am trying to applying android:foreground attributes but it can't solve it.. @PPartisan

Comment: It seems you need to play with the transparency for the upper layers. Keep your background image as a drawable and assign it to your background layer or use and Image which allows you some tricks to crop and scale it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="@color/blue_600"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".UI.Activity.HomeActivity">


<ScrollView
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:orientation="vertical"
       android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
       android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
       android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:background="#54e5e5e5"
           android:layout_height="200dp">

       </RelativeLayout>

       <RelativeLayout
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:background="#54e5e5e5"
           android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
           android:layout_height="200dp">

       </RelativeLayout>
   </LinearLayout>
```

if you want you can use scroll view.